# Jenkins Node Image at Kubernetes Plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, kubernetes, python

I'm working on huge pipeline with different development environment (python, node, java). 
For manage this CI pipeline our teams using Jenkins at Kubernetes environment.

I want to give PipeLine node annotation at Groovy Script show as below .

```
 node("test-py") {
   sh "python -m -v py.test TEST_FILE.py "
 }
```

How I can create pod with image , with Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation presented here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin

You need to specify a Kubernetes pod in your pipeline. An example of your use case would look similar to this for a single python container. You'll notice that containers: [] expects an array so you can include additional containers.

```
def label = "mypod-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'python', image: 'python:3.7-alpine', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
]) {
    node(label) {
        stage('Get a Python project') {
            git 'https://github.com/oğuz/project.git'
            container('python') {
                stage('Test a Python project') {
                    sh "python -m -v py.test TEST_FILE.py "
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've runned this template groovy script before . I found the code block at kubernetes plugin , by the default is JNLP_SLAVE at it is offical image  at link:  https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave/  so that we change default : JNLP_SLAVE notation . Thanks for your answer :))